# Unable to insert value into SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

So I created a simple table:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friendList (name)''')
```

I then have a variable 'nombre' which holds the string 'Gabriel'.

I then try the following:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO friendList VALUES (nombre);")
```

And get this:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: nombre
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO friendList VALUES (?)", (nombre,))
conn.commit()  <-- important, needed to save transaction
```

Since `nombre` is a variable, you can bind it this way. You *could* insert it directly by concatenating, but this opens you up to SQL Injection.

Comment: Python accepts this with no error messages. When I commit it and view the database in my SQL Browser the database has no entries.

Comment: You likely need to commit your transaction, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html.

Comment: I was committing it.  I tried the updated line of code and that works now.

Comment: How would I add two variables to the database?  Like nombre1 and nobre2?  Thanks.

Comment: You can run `c.execute()` multiple times, and they'll all get committed to the database when you run `commit()`.

Comment: But how would you insert two variables with one line of code? c.execute("INSERT INTO friendList VALUES (?)", (nombre1,nombre2,)) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use VALUES (?, ?), one ? per variable.

Comment: I've tried c.execute("INSERT INTO friendList VALUES (?, ?)", (nombre1,nombre2,)) and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have two columns in your table? Your original post shows only one column in the table.